# want to change the size for \mathsf throughout my document

Tags: fontsize, math-fonts, sansmathfonts

When I put an \overline, \overrightarrow etc. on an uppercase \mathsf letter the result is too large to fit in an inline equation with the default \baselineskip. This results in uneven line spacing, and IMHO doesn't look right even in displayed equations. This is also true of \mathrm and other shapes, but I only use such decorations on \mathsf letters.

I presume there is a way redefine the \mathsf font shape to be a bit smaller than the default throughout my document, but the documentation on e.g. \DeclareLMathAlphabet & \SetMathAlphabet in the font guide is pretty terse, and the few examples therein don't apply to what I want to do. Advice greatly appreciated!

Here's a simple example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{newtxmath}

\addtolength{\parskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}

This is a line of text with an inline equation in it that contains a
\verb=\mathsf= character string that shows that it does not fit with
an \verb=\overrightarrow= over it, $\overrightarrow{\mathsf{AB}}$,
i.e.~the spacing on the last line is larger than the first.

This is a line of text with an inline equation in it that shows if you
change font to \verb=\mathrm= you get the same problem,
$\overrightarrow{\mathrm{AB}}$ (but I only use \verb=\overrightarrow=
on \verb=\mathsf=).

What I've been doing is to make the \verb=\mathsf= characters are bit
smaller by wrapping my equations in \verb={\small ... }=, like this
{\small$\overrightarrow{\mathsf{AB}}$}, but it's a PITA having to do
that everywhere (even in displayed equations for consistency).

So, I'd like to make all my \verb=\mathsf= text say 10\% smaller, and
of course this size change should apply equally in
\verb=\displaystyle=, \verb=\textstyle=, \verb=\scriptstyle= and
\verb=\scriptscriptstyle=.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a small example of code showing the issue so we can play with it?

Comment: @egreg I'm afraid I can't given the strict character limits in comments, but you can find a simple example here: https://gist.github.com/TimFH/d6198fa7801c1a56acf9fe53959e55b7

Comment: You can edit your question after you have posted it. The example should not be too long for the question (even though it is probably too long for the comments).

Comment: Question edited to include my example.

Answer (score 2):

Use for example the package **esvect**, and the command `\vv`. You can customize the shape of the arrow.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\addtolength{\parskip}{3pt}

\begin{document}

This is a line of text with an inline equation in it that contains
a \verb=\mathsf= character string that shows that it \textbf{does fit} 
with an \verb=\vv= over it, $\vv{\mathsf{AB}}$, i.e.~the spacing on the last 
line is \textbf{the same} than the first.

This is a line of text with an inline equation in it that shows if you change 
font to \verb=\mathrm= you get the same \textbf{correct} line spacing, 
$\vv{\mathrm{AB}}$ (bla bla bla, so there is 3 line of text in this paragraph).

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This may be an oversight (I haven't tested), but you *do* in the code for your example apply `\vv` also to `\mathrm`, which contradicts the text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have used the text provided by OP. I have not adapted the text "(but I only use \vv on \mathsf)". I will modify this with dummy text (so there is still 3 line of text in the second paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `newtxmath` without also changing the text font to Times.

Of course, the package of choice is `newtxtext`, which also loads Helvetica for sans serif. In order to scale Helvetica, you can load `newtxtext` with the `nohelv` option and load `helvet` with a scaling option.

Also `esvect` is useful for the overarrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nohelv]{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{helvet}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{esvect}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{esvect}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> vect5
  <5.5-6.5> vect6
  <6.5-7.5> vect7
  <7.5-8.5> vect8
  <8.5-9.5> vect9
  <9.5-> vect10
}{}


\begin{document}

This is a line of text with an inline equation in it that contains a
\verb=\mathsf= character string that shows that it does not fit with
an \verb=\vv= over it, $\vv{\mathsf{AB}}$,
i.e.~the spacing on the last line is larger than the first.

\end{document}
```

The font shape declarations are needed because `esvect` has a `.fd` file that only loads fonts at fixed sizes (but it provides scalable Type1 fonts).

[image]

Here's the output if the call to `helvet` is replaced by

```
\usepackage[type1,sfdefault,scale=0.85]{sourcesanspro}
```

[image]

I'd recommend it over Helvetica.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed account of how I can scale down the \mathsf shape a bit! It seems to be just what I wanted, however: When I try to load the newtxtext package with the "nohelv" option, I get: "! Package xkeyval Error: `nohelv' undefined in families `ntx'". Do I have to \usepackage{newtx} instead (as is -- poorly! -- described in https://texdoc.org/serve/newtx/0)?

Comment: Fortunately, \usepackage[helvratio=0.9]{newtxtext} followed by \usepackage{newtxmath} seems to do exactly what I wanted, without the need for anything else! And I prefer Times anyway -:)